# GWT - how to get widget background color in HSL format

Tags: gwt

How to get a widget background color (with pure gwt) in HSL format? I tried using for example `label.getElement().getStyle().getBackgroundColor();` but it always returns color in RGB format though the original one is `#FFFFFF` :S

Please share some useful tips

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert RBG value to HSL:

http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript

Comment: You mean using JSNI? But is there some pure GWT lib or something?

Comment: The math in that function is just math - strip off the `function`, replace the `var` with `int`, and return `int[]` and you've essentially got it in Java.